# Access to variable in ActionEvent-Class

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

```
btnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    var1 = Float.parseFloat(txtBox.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException n) {
                }
            }
        });
```

I can't access to the variable 'var1' here, i get the error:

> local variable var1 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

How can i get access to variables in the actionPerformed event? Declaring as final is not usefull because changing final variables value is not possible.

Comment: 1) `catch(NumberFormatException n)
                {

                }` Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The inner class `ActionListener` holds  a copy of the local variable. If the variable changes in the local class the inner class variable might be out of sync.

I think better  to make it global (field):

```
 private float var1; 

 ...

 btnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                var1 = Float.parseFloat(txtBox.getText());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException n) {
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: After carefully re-reading both the question and your answer, I realized the first approach will not work, since *"Declaring as final is not usefull because changing final variables value is not possible."*  The 2nd strategy should work.

Comment: If i make it global as private i get: non-static varaible var1 cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: It happens because `btnButton.addActionListener` defined in static method. post all your method please

Comment: @binaryBigInt   BTW, you can set `private static float var1; `

Comment: if i set it to private static float var1, i get: local variable var1 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final. I can't post the hole code in here because it is too muchf or the comment-box and i can't answer my own questions because i am under 10 reputations....

Comment: post `private static float var1;` under `public class XXXX {`

Comment: it is under the class

Answer (score 2):

```
var1 = Float.parseFloat(txtBox.getText());
```

Make that variable as `member`  variable.

```
class outer {
  //declare  variable here 

btnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
   // assign here

}

// you can use it later
```

[JLS # chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.

An example here from spec:

Comment: If you make it final, you wouldn't be able to assign it :-) OP would need to make it a member, or to define a mutable wrapper.

Comment: If i make var1 final i am not able to access it anymore (as written in the first post). If i make it private, i get the message:

    illegal message

Comment: @binaryBigInt  If you declare them as member variables you can.no need to make them final.

Comment: If i do it like so:

public class testClass
{
    private float var1;
    
}
i get:

non static variable var1 cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @binaryBigInt Can you please post the full code. You are accessing that in a static context As error showing. Post full code.

Comment: i can't post full code because i am under 10 reputations therefore i can't answer myself (and posting 15 lines of code in the comment box is not usefull for anyone.